# MVC update the database based on a non primary key value

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a database table that looks like this:

[image: table]

My goal is to update my "unavail" table based on the ID of either the component, part, or item depending on which one is relevant in my situation.

For example, if the partID = 43 I want to add to the 'unavail' column

I first started working on this by trying this

```
db.OffSiteItemDetails.Find(sod.PartID).unavail += sod.comp_returned;
```

**(Where sod.PartId = 43)**

But I quickly realized it was just checking for where the "ID" was equal to 43 which isn't what I want. After some investigation I saw people suggesting using

```
db.Where(x => x.non-pk == value)
```

So I created this

```
db.OffSiteItemDetails.Where(x => x.componentID == sod.ComponentID);
```

But from here I don't know how to change my unavail table values.

This was a tough question to type so if you need more clarity just ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var item in db.OffSiteItemDetails.Where(x => x.componentID == sod.ComponentID))
{
    // item.unavail = [new value]
    // db.Update(item);
    // ...I don't know how you update the data in your database
}
```

Something like that?